# Bootstrap Modal Position issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I want to divide the screen as **left menu** and **main menu** with Bootstrap.

Left Menu will be **"col-md-2"** and Main Menu will be **"col-md-10"** and I'd like to make main menu as a overlay screen.

For this reason, I am using bootstrap modal. As you can see in my below code:

1-) I cannot use **"col-md-xx"** class into Modal class

2-) If I set the **80%** width to **class="modal-dialog**", it is nearly working but left position is being wrong

3-) Therefore, I am setting the modal position with jQuery but it is still now working properly.

I know that it is very diffucult to explain but if you check the below code I suppose you will understand the situation.

Do you have any suggestion to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>-</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #leftmenu,
        #mainmenu {
            border-style: solid;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        var aa = 1;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myModal").modal({
                backdrop: 'static'
            });

            $("#myModal2").width($("#mainmenu").width());
            $("#myModal2").offset({
                left: $("#mainmenu").position().left // (if I add to "-150" end of this line it will be ok but I cannot set hardcoded number)
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="leftmenu" class="col-md-2">Left Menu</div>
        <div id="mainmenu" class="col-md-10">
            Main
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div id="myModal2" class="modal-dialog" style="width:80%;">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn2">Open Modal2</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Um its really not clear, did you only overly  main area and modal should not effect left bar correct ?  like visit here  http://garhwalonline.com/alchemy/ and click on image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

CSS:

```
.left-zero {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
 }
```

Change into HTML:

```
<div id="myModal2" class="modal-dialog left-zero">
```

Comment: It is working.. That's great! Thank you so much @Md Mahfuzur Rahman